# can I get xml tag value to be used in in html, or can I use <ul> & <il> in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

basically I have a homework to get xml data and display it in html page, so the xml data is looked like this

```
<job>
 <id>4821a</id>
 <title>Engineer On Site</title>
 <url>https://www.google.com/</url>
 <company_name>Fast Connection, Ltd.</company_name>
 <company_logo>https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg</company_logo>
 <country>United States</country>
 <jobCategory>Engineering</jobCategory>
 <jobIndustry>Information Technology and Services</jobIndustry>
 <employmentType>Contract</employmentType>
 </job>
```

with a section of html code look like this

```
<section class="site-section">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="job mb-5">
          <li class="job d-block d-sm-flex pb-3 pb-sm-0 align-items-center">
            <a href="jobexample.html"></a>
            <div class="job-logo">
              <img src="images/job_logo_2.jpg" alt="Free Website Template by Free-Template.co" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="job-about d-sm-flex custom-width w-100 justify-content-between mx-4">
              <div class="job-position custom-width w-50 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                <h2>Insert-Job</h2>
                <strong>Insert-Company</strong>
              </div>
              <div class="job-location mb-3 mb-sm-0 custom-width w-25">
                <span class="icon-room"></span> Insert-City 
              </div>
              <div class="job-meta">
                <span class="badge badge-success">Insert-emplyementtype</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
```

so basically I have to get the xml data and show it to html page

based on my searches, usually the UI component of the html page is inserted inside the script, however we were told to make "better UI using tags like section, ul, & li" instead of barebone table, and I couldn't find tutorial if someone has inserted the tags inside the script itself

so my idea was getting the xml data as variable value, then show the variable value through normal meant

could it be done, or should I insert the tags inside the script itself?

edit: and could I use 'for' to repeatedly get & show xml data if my xml file has multiple data, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to read your XML information. From that point it's easy to create and add elements. Example to get you started:

```js
let text = '';
text+= '<job>';
text+= '<id>4821a</id>';
text+= '<title>Engineer On Site</title>';
text+= '<url>https://www.google.com/</url>';
text+= '<company_name>Fast Connection, Ltd.</company_name>';
text+= '<company_logo>https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg</company_logo>';
text+= '<country>United States</country>';
text+= '<jobCategory>Engineering</jobCategory>';
text+= '<jobIndustry>Information Technology and Services</jobIndustry>';
text+= '<employmentType>Contract</employmentType>';
text+= '</job>';
let parser = new DOMParser();
let xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
let countries = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('country');
console.log(countries[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); // United States

let ulist = document.createElement('ul');
let listitem = document.createElement('li');
listitem.innerText = countries[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

ulist.appendChild(listitem)
document.body.appendChild(ulist);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so I have to add the xml code inside DOMParser script? could I use separate xml file?

Comment: Nope that's just an example. You can get that text from anywhere.